# Programmatically added buttons click event

Tags: c#, winforms, button, dynamic

I am making a winform project where the user will enter the items to be sold. 
When the user gets in to sales screen , some buttons will be generated from the data user provided . I need to catch the click event of each button.

To give an example :
 In the datatable :

- coca cola          2.00$
- Pepsi              2.50$
- diet pepsi         3.00$
- pepsi max          1.50$

User will fill in the items and prices so there is no precise # of items to be shown.

When in the form if the user presses coca cola button twice and pepsi once I need to list them and tell the total .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have an indeterminate number of Buttons, I would use a Common Event Handler like user2353972's example shows. You can then determine which button was clicked by casting the sender object to a Button.  You can then access all of the property's of your button including the `Text` and the `Tag` object property which you can then use to determine your price.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var b = (Button)sender;

    switch(b.Text)  //Do your 
    {
        case "Coca Cola":
            break;
        case "Pepsi":
            break;
        case "Diet Pepsi":
            break;
        case "Pepsi Max":
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

just new the button,and bind the click event to your method.
like：

```
Button b=new Button();
b.Click+=new EventHandler(b_Click);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would agree with Mark Hall; that's the way to go. I suggest just minor syntactical improvement: use

```
switch ((sender As Button).Text)
```

to simplify the code. Regards, AB